# Preventing page (folder) redirection with Awardspace hosting

Tags: apache, lamp, shared-hosting

I'm using LAMP hosting on AwardSpace.com.

I have a private folder `foobar` and when a page </foobar> is requested, it redirects with a 301 to </foobar/> (, allowing pentesters to tell that the folder exists). This is so even after adding a htaccess file:

```
rewriteengine on
rewriterule foobar$ testpage.php
```

I believe the server itself is doing the redirection regardless of my hosting content.

How can the redirect be prevented?

---

<sub>(Tried removing traversal access to the folder but it shows 403 and testpage.php doesn't load.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

(For undocumented behavior,) To prevent folders being 301ed‑with‑slash‑appended, you can add a redirect flag to the rewrite rule:

```
rewriterule foobar$ /testpage.php [r]
```

With that, no one will know that `foobar` is actually a folder.

---

Suppose HTTP redirection is unwanted, `r` can be appended with `=x` where `x` is a value that doesn't cause redirection. This can be `305`. This can be `510`. This can be `200`.  In such cases the 3rd argument is ignored ([cf](http://archive.is/PLGyv#selection-2695.296-2699.10)):

```
rewriterule foobar$ yadadadaada [r=200]
```

---

Suppose that content is required, content can be added:

```
errordocument 200 "test page"
```

, or:

```
errordocument 200 /testpage.php
```